# How to set up RSS feed with a Jekyll site?

Tags: github, rss, jekyll, github-pages

I am in the process of setting up a blog with GitHub Pages and jekyll on linux. I am using the included "minima" theme, which includes a "Subscribe vie RSS" link at the bottom of the page. When I click this link, I get a message saying:
`This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.` and a whole lot of xml below it. I am not quite sure how an RSS feed works, but I am pretty sure that it's not supposed to work like this. My xml file is as follows:

```html
<feed>
<generator uri="https://jekyllrb.com/" version="3.8.5">Jekyll</generator>
<link href="https://gaetgu.github.io/feed.xml" rel="self" type="application/atom+xml"/>
<link href="https://gaetgu.github.io/" rel="alternate" type="text/html"/>
<updated>2020-02-03T16:52:33+00:00</updated>
<id>https://gaetgu.github.io/feed.xml</id>
<title type="html">Gaetgu</title>
<subtitle>Copyright© 2020 Gabriel Gutiérrez</subtitle>
<entry>
<title type="html">site launched</title>
<link href="https://gaetgu.github.io/blog/site-launched" rel="alternate" type="text/html" title="site launched"/>
<published>2020-01-28T00:00:00+00:00</published>
<updated>2020-01-28T00:00:00+00:00</updated>
<id>https://gaetgu.github.io/blog/site-launched</id>
<content type="html" xml:base="https://gaetgu.github.io/blog/site-launched">
<h2 id="hello-world-this-is-the-first-post-of-the-gaetgu-ae-website">Hello, World! This is the first post of the Gaetgu AE website!!!</h2> <p>This blog will contain AE content etc.</p>
</content>
<author>
<name>Gaetgu</name>
</author>
<summary type="html">
Hello, World! This is the first post of the Gaetgu AE website!!!
</summary>
</entry>
<entry>
<title type="html">TVC on Model Rockets</title>
<link href="https://gaetgu.github.io/blog/model-rockets" rel="alternate" type="text/html" title="TVC on Model Rockets"/>
<published>2020-01-28T00:00:00+00:00</published>
<updated>2020-01-28T00:00:00+00:00</updated>
<id>https://gaetgu.github.io/blog/model-rockets</id>
<content type="html" xml:base="https://gaetgu.github.io/blog/model-rockets">
<h3 id="thrust-vectoring-control">Thrust Vectoring Control</h3> <p>TVC is an acronymn for <strong>T</strong>hrust <strong>V</strong>ectoring <strong>C</strong>ontrol. TVC works by gimballing the motor in the base of a model rocket, changing the angle of thrust and therefore changing the velocity.</p> <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7a/En_Gimbaled_thrust_diagram.svg" alt="TVC Diagram" /></p> <p>This is done actively, changing the course of the rocket and stabilizing it from outside factors such as wind. This concept is what allows SpaceX to land their rockets.</p> <p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Gimbaled_thrust_animation.gif" alt="TVC Animation" /></p> <p>Up until fairly recently, the idea of equipping a model rocket with TVC seemed an out-of-reach concept. Once the 3d printer was made affordable and small, people were suddenly able to create their own parts, without having to have access to a machine shop or spend insane amounts of money to get it custom-built and shipped to your location. The PLA used to print parts is also lighter than acrylic and metal, while still being fairly strong, allowing its use in flight vehicles. As for as I know, there is currently only one company, BPS, who is selling a kit to create your own TVC system, though you could create your own gimbal with a personal 3d printer. The main downside to trying to DUY instead of buying a kit is that you also have to create your own flight computer.</p> <h3 id="building-a-tvc-equipped-rocket-through-kit">Building a TVC-equipped Rocket (through kit)</h3> <p>The kit sold by BPS currently costs $349, and is out of stock until sometime spring 2020. The motor gimbal and avionics mount fit inside a 74mm airframe. The airframes can be bought <a href="https://www.apogeerockets.com/Building_Supplies/Body_Tubes/ Low_Power_Tubes/74mm_x_18_Body_Tube_Thin_Wall_3_tube">here</a>. You must use a MicroSD card to program the main avionics, which can be bought <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004ZIENBA" rel="nofollow noreferrer">here</a>. And you must buy either a rechargeable LiPo battery or a 9-volt, the LiPos can be found <a href="https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N32628C" rel="nofollow noreferrer">here</a>. And finally, you must buy motor tubes to fit the motor into the housing, you can buy two of <a href="https://www.apogeerockets.com/Building_Supplies/Body_Tubes/Low_Power_Tubes/ 29mm_x_13_Body_Tube_Holds_FG_Engines">these</a>. A beginner rocket, the Electron, can be built along with BPS’s YouTube™ series, as seen below.</p> <p><a href="https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyV774-3p835n5XZFz4JMvF-Griy_uOdV"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/1BQkMYj6Kps/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCNACELwBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&amp;rs=AOn4CLCZ49T8hDn5S7x3LKA17FYI2S4r3g" alt="Build TVC Series" /></a></p>
</content>
<author>
<name>Gaetgu</name>
</author>
<summary type="html">Thrust Vectoring Control</summary>
</entry>
</feed>
```

I am using the jekyll-feed plugin. This content is actually not found in my github repo, so I assume it's auto-generated and hidden by the plugin. The repo can be found [here](https://github.com/gaetgu/gaetgu.github.io) and the website affiliated with it [here](https://gaetgu.github.io) Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it looks a bit off, it is working correctly.

You'd add the link to that file in your RSS reader, then that XML file is periodically read to build a feed.

Comment: It looks weird because it's an [Atom feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(Web_standard)), not an RSS feed (even though Minima refers to it as RSS). Seems like most feed readers work with RSS or Atom formats though.